# Export the PowerShell output to a text file in tab-delimited format

Tags: powershell, csv

How do I save the PowerShell script output to a text file in tab-delimited format?

*Example -* How do I export the output of the below PowerShell script to text, tab-delimited format?

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Database data01 |ft displayname,databasename,itemcount,totalitemsize
```

Answer (score 61):

Use the `Export-CSV` with a tab delimiter. Note, that you can't use the output of `format-table` as an input to `export-CSV`, use `select-object` instead:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Database data01 |
  select displayname,databasename,itemcount,totalitemsize |
  export-csv -delimiter "`t" -path theOutFile.txt -notype
```

Comment: I got the output as tab delimited format .but the output contains double quotes which separates each column 

I am using this tab delimited file as a input file  to SQL .

Since this text file contains double quotes in a null value sql reads and updates the same 

is there any way to remove those doublequotes while exporting itself..?

Comment: Hi , I have managed to get the output without quotes , 

have used -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')}  this command and got the output as expected. 

Thanks for your help ..